# Заполнение структуры IMAGE_NT_HEADER при помощи указателя на образ в памяти

Tags: c++

Пишу функцию для преобразования `RVA` в `VA`.

```
unsigned myRVAtoRAW (HANDLE pe_image, unsigned rva)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header;
    std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dos_header), pe_image, sizeof(dos_header));

    if (dos_header.e_magic != 'ZM')
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read IMAGE_DOS_HEADER" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Start of PE header must be DWORD-aligned
    if (dos_header.e_lfanew % sizeof(DWORD) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "PE header is not DWORD-aligned" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 nt_headers;
std::memcpy(&nt_headers,
            (char *)  pe_image + dos_header.e_lfanew, sizeof(nt_headers));

if (nt_headers.Signature != 'EP')
{
    std::cout << "Incorrent PE signature" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Пояснение по коду: первый параметр функции - это адрес начала проекции исполняемого файла на адресное пространство данной программы. Его возвращает функция `MapViewOfFile`.

Функция правильно читает `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`, проверка `MZ`-сигнатуры проходит без ошибок.

Затем нужно прочитать `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32`. Поле `dos_header.e_lfanew` указывает на начало PE-заголовка, т.е. на первый байт `PE00`. Я подумал, что этот адрес задается относительно начала файла в памяти, т.к. за 10 минут не нагуглил, какой именно адрес здесь содержится.

Приведу примеры того, как я заполнял эту структуру.

```
std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nt_headers),
           (char *)pe_image + dos_header.e_lfanew, sizeof(nt_headers));
```

Выше - единственное, что не приводит к ошибкам. Считаю, что `e_lfanew` - относительный адрес.

```
std::memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&nt_headers), 
            dos_header.e_lfanew, sizeof(nt_headers));
```

Вызывает ошибку при запуске программы.

И еще: если дан указатель на проекцию файла, как в C++ будет корректно через него заполнять структуры? Функция memcpy не позволяет отслеживать, например, такие ошибки, когда данных меньше, чем размер структуры.

Дополнение: функция как будто правильно выполняет преобразование адресов.
Дополнение: здесь я, наверно, не учел адрес начала секции кода.

```
unsigned myRVAtoRAW (HANDLE pe_image, unsigned rva)
{
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header;
    std::memcpy(&dos_header, pe_image, sizeof(dos_header));

    if (dos_header.e_magic != 'ZM')
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to read IMAGE_DOS_HEADER" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Start of PE header must be DWORD-aligned
    if (dos_header.e_lfanew % sizeof(DWORD) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "PE header is not DWORD-aligned" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS nt_headers;
    std::memcpy(&nt_headers,
                 ((char *) pe_image) + dos_header.e_lfanew, sizeof(nt_headers));

    // Check: is our file PE
    if (nt_headers.Signature != 'EP')
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrent PE signature" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Check: is this file PE32
    if (nt_headers.OptionalHeader.Magic != 0x10B)
    {
        std::cout << "This PE is not PE32" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "ImageBase = " << nt_headers.OptionalHeader.ImageBase << std::endl;

    // Calculate RVA to VA
    return rva + nt_headers.OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
}
```

Comment: e_lfanew - файловое смещение PE-заголовка, все правильно. Смотрите в отладчике что у вас по этому смещению.

Comment: И да, забудьте про *_cast пока вы не работаете с объектами и точно не понимаете что это и зачем.

Comment: Заменил все приведения типов на (char *)

Comment: Исправил и убрал лишнее приведение типа. Там достаточно оператора &. Но раз уж я пишу на C++, можно пользоваться его удобствами и, может быть, в нем есть какие-то более правильные способы заполнения структура. Например, при считывании структур из файла используются потоки. Но здесь работа идет с памятью.

Comment: Самое удобное, раз вы уже замапили файл - использовать указатели на нужные структуры.

Comment: ((char *)  pe_image) + dos_header.e_lfanew попробуйте.
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS используйте вместо явного указания разрядности, если вы, конечно, не собираете свою софтину под x64

Comment: Добавил написанную функцию в конец. Теперь делаю проверку: я знаю, какие два байта показывает Олли по адресу 401000 в программе, которую я замапил, теперь надо их напечатать. Я завел две переменные a и b, преобразовал адрес 401000 в абсолютный и сохранил его в переменной raw. Переменные заполняю так: memcpy(&a, (char *) raw, 1). При запуске возникает ошибка c0000005 - нарушение доступа к памяти. Откуда она? Я ведь назначил образу все права доступа.

Comment: Отладчик - ваш друг. Почему бы его не использовать, а?